# Using CPT for summer work authorization on an F1 visa while OPT Application still Pending

Tags: working, usa

Is anyone aware of whether it is okay to use the [CPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curricular_Practical_Training) (curricular practical training) while your [OPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_Practical_Training) (optional practical training) application is still pending?

I am currently waiting for the cancellation of my OPT application to go through so that I can apply for CPT but my start date is coming up so I was wondering if it is fine to use the CPT even thought the OPT application is still pending (but soon to be cancelled)?

Comment: It's probably best if you state your circustances more clearly and expand any acronym. This will allow even those not specifically knowledgeable with your situation to research it.

Comment: @ouflak the acromyms are explained at the start

Comment: Cool. I'll update the question. What do you want to 'use' the CPT for? Maintenance of your F1? I'm not very familiar with this, having just googled it.

Comment: @ouflak work authorisation for the summer  on an F1 visa

Comment: Ok, I've updated the title. Is that about right?